# Change schema of the parquet

Tags: pyspark, schema, metadata, parquet

I have predefied the schema and would like to read the parquet file with that predfied schema. Unfortunetly, when I apply the schema I get errors for multiple columns that did not match the data types

```
schema = StructType()
length = len(cdm['definitions'][0]['hasAttributes']) - 1
for index1, attribute in enumerate(cdm['definitions'][0]['hasAttributes']):
    if (attribute['dataFormat'] in ('Int32', 'Time')) and (index1 != length):
        field = StructField(attribute['name'],IntegerType(),True)
        schema.add(field)
    elif attribute['dataFormat'] in ('DateTime') and (index1 != length):
        field = StructField(attribute['name'],TimestampType(),True)
        schema.add(field)
    elif attribute['dataFormat'] in ('String') and (index1 != length):
        field = StructField(attribute['name'],StringType(),True)
        schema.add(field)
    elif attribute['dataFormat'] in ('Int64') and (index1 != length):
        field = StructField(attribute['name'],LongType(),True)
        schema.add(field)
    elif attribute['dataFormat'] in ('Decimal') and (index1 != length):
        field = StructField(attribute['name'],DecimalType(38, 20),True)
        schema.add(field)
    elif index1 == length:
        field = StructField(attribute['name'],StringType(),True)
        schema.add(field)
        LastColumnName = attribute['name']
        LastColumnDataType = attribute['dataFormat']
    else:
        field = StructField(attribute['name'],StringType(),True)
        schema.add(field)

df2 = (spark.read.format('parquet')
       .option("path", '/mnt/bronze/D365/Snapshot/'+table_name+"/20230414061932/*.parquet")
       .schema(schema)
       .load()
  )
```

error:

> Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [AmountCur], Expected: DecimalType(38,20), Found: FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY
> Caused by: SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException:

Is there solution for this?